# Recreating a famous 1980s synthesizser effect

Tags: sound-effects

The effect I'm trying to recreate is a "rising" type of effect that is sort of a 1980s cliche, and can be heard on many tracks from the period.  For example, it can be heard at approximately 0:58 on Dead or Alive's "You Spin Me Round (Like A Record)", and on the 1985 Rush song "The Big Money" at approximately 0:44.

Any suggestions on how to go about recreating this with a modern digital or virtual analog synthesizer?

Comment: A fast arpeggiator is the clue.